# iOS 8 apply blur gradually

Tags: ios, ios8, uiblureffect

I want to apply blur gradually while scrolling a content. I this it's possible because this effect is present in the new spotlight search. When you pull down the home screen to reveal the search bar, the system apply a gradually blur to the home screen.

Is there an option in `UIVisualEffectView` class or `UIBlurEffect` ?

Comment: The option is called `yourBlurView.alpha`

Comment: Use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Comment: @SergiusGee if you change the alpha the console give a warning that say that the blur effect is broken until the alpha reach the value of 1